# Getting a UK visa more quickly

Tags: visas, uk

I need to apply for a UK visa.  The earliest appointment in any Northern California USCIS is not until mid June, and I am leaving mid July.  On the UK.gov visa page, they say that it takes 3 to 5 weeks for the visa to be approved.

I have found two ways to get it more quickly:

1. Apply at VFS center in San Francisco with bronze package at $410
2. Fly out to Southern California to do the biometrics in one of the offices

If I were to choose the bronze package, will this include biometrics at the VFS office?  Does this also include courier costs to and from the UK NY consulate?  How long does this take from the time I have the appointment to my getting my passport back?

Another possibility is go for a walk-in at the local USCIS.  Will they even let me come in & get the biometrics done?

Comment: What does USCIS have to do with a UK visa?

Comment: @mdd It is where you give biometrics if you apply for a UK visa in the USA with standard (not priority or premium) service. See the [special instructions](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply for a premium service from VFS to submit your UK visa application in the USA, your biometrics will be taken at the VFS visa application centre (VAC). You do not need to visit a USCIS ASC separately. This applies to all services from Bronze level upward. See also [What happens at the premium application centre](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/us/en/vacs/what-happens-at-the-vac)

I've heard of people being able to walk in at the USCIS ASC, but if I were in a hurry I wouldn't count on being able to do it.

Comment: The earliest appointment at VFS office in San Francisco is June 5; so while it’s not as late as the USCIS Northern California appointment, it is still quite a while.  I could make appointment for a Southern California appointment as early as this week.  I am weighing my options as the costs will pretty much the same, but will go for one that gets my visa quicker.

Comment: @ccossc You can add [walk-in service](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/us/en/premium-services/walk-in-without-appointment) for $75 and go right away without an appointment.

Comment: Update June 18, 2019...  I did a walk-in to USCIS in Santa Clara on May 22.  The officer in the front desk let me in.  I was in and out within an hour.  I sent in my application form along with documents to NY the next day.  Waited for almost a month, and just got my passport with the visa attached.  Thank you Michael Hampton for your help...

Comment: @ccossc did you pay for the walk-in service then or did you just take a chance walking into the Santa Clara one?